# abp.io AddRazorRuntimeCompilation for dependent projects

Tags: abp

I need to modify extensively the Volo.Abp.Account.Web project (register.cshtml, etc.). Testing changes to views, js, and so on without rebuild is a must.

I've tried configuring run time compilation without success:

In Startup.cs:

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

In AbpAccountWebModule.cs:

```
context.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Is this a .NET Core limitation? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I used the page override as mentionned here:
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/master/UI/AspNetCore/Customization-User-Interface

And can now modify the page and view the changes without rebuild.